# IE CSS Alignment Issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float

My issue is that I have two dropdown boxes that I need to align.  In Firefox, it works fine.  Basically, one form box for country, and then underneath it, another form box for state.  In IE, these boxes show up next to one another.  I'm trying to style it so that the second form box appears underneath the first.

My HTML code (I chopped off some states so it'd be easier to read):

```
<div class="label">*Country:</div>
<div class="field">
  <asp:DropDownList ID="country" CssClass="country2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>    
</div>
<div class="label"></div>
<div class="field">
  <asp:DropDownList ID="us_states" runat="server" CssClass="us_state_dropdown2">
    <asp:ListItem>-Select State-</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Alabama</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Alaska</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Arizona</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

My CSS code for classes "label", "field", "country2", and "us_state_dropdown2":

```
.label {width: 195px !important; height: 28px; }
.field {width: auto !important;}
.country2 { width:212px !important;}
.us_state_dropdown2 { width:212px !important;}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any rules being applied to `div`s in that context such as `float`?

Comment: The full CSS (I omitted the stuff I didn't think was relevant):
 
#contact_form .label {width: 195px !important; height: 28px; }
#contact_form .field {width: auto !important;}
.question {float: left; width: 100%;}
.question .label {height: auto !important;}
.question .field {margin-top:0px !important; }
.country2 { width:212px !important;}
.us_state_dropdown2 { width:212px !important;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clear` to avoid elements from being positioned on the side(s) that you choose.
Read the CSS reference to learn how to use `clear`. [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/clear)

Comment: Even if I put "clear:both !important;" on this, I still see the same behavior.  It was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: @ndisdabest, Can you provide the relevant source of the page? It will be easier for people without an ASP server to test the answer. You can paste to http://www.jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Never mind, I was able to figure it out.  Just wrapped it in another DIV and it seemed to work fine.